# webrtc audio device disconnection and reconnection

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I have a video call application based on WebRTC. It is working as expected. However when call is going on, if I disconnect and connect back audio device (mic + speaker), only speaker part is working. The mic part seems to be not working - the other side can't hear anymore.

Is there any way to inform WebRTC to take audio input again once audio device is connected back?

Comment: Is it your application, or are you merely using it? If this is a programming question, what language are you using, and what libraries, if any, are involved? The short answer is yes, but some context or code would help ensure I'm answering the right question.

Comment: It is my application developed in node.js as signalling server, end points are on browser (html, java script). Using webrtc library and everything else normal java script. Hope this gives some context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to inform WebRTC to take audio input again once audio device is connected back?

Your question appears simple—the symmetry with speakers is alluring—but once we're dealing with users who have multiple cameras and microphones, it's not that simple: If your user disconnects their bluetooth headset they were using, should you wait for them to reconnect it, or immediately switch to their laptop microphone? If the latter, do you switch back if they reconnect it later? These are application decisions.

The APIs to handle these things are: primarily the [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/onended) and [devicechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/ondevicechange) events, and the [replaceTrack()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack) method. You may also need the [deviceId](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Syntax) constraint, and the [enumerateDevices()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) method to a handle multiple devices.

However, to keep things simple, let's take the assumptions in your question at face value to explore the APIs:

When the user unplugs their sole microphone (not their camera) mid-call, our job is to resume conversation with it when they reinsert it, without dropping video:

1. First, we listen to the `ended` event to learn when our local audio track drops.
2. When that happens, we listen for a `devicechange` event to detect re-insertion (of anything).
3. When that happens, we *could* check what changed using *enumerateDevices()*, or simply try *getUserMedia* again (microphone only this time).
4. If that succeeds, use `await sender.replaceTrack(newAudioTrack)` to send our new audio.

This might look like this:

```
let sender;

(async () => {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true});
    pc.addTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0], stream);
    sender = pc.addTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0], stream);
    sender.track.onended = () => navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange = tryAgain;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();

async function tryAgain() {
  try {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
    await sender.replaceTrack(stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
    navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange = null;
    sender.track.onended = () => navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange = tryAgain;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.name == "NotFoundError") return;
    console.log(e);
  }
}

// Your usual WebRTC negotiation code goes here
```

The above is for illustration only. I'm sure there are lots of corner cases to consider.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Will give a try on suggested approach.